# In leetcode why am I getting the error "NameError: global name 'climbStairs' is not defined"? but works without 'self' and 'object'?

Tags: python

Here is the code:

```
class Solution(object):
    
    def climbStairs(self, n):
        if n in {0,1}:
            return 1
        else:
            return climbStairs(n-2) + climbStairs(n-1)
```

Full error message:

```
NameError: global name 'climbStairs' is not defined
    return climbStairs(n-2) + climbStairs(n-1)
Line 7 in climbStairs (Solution.py)
    ret = Solution().climbStairs(param_1)
Line 29 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 39 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

I am thinking this has something to do with scope. Tried this in Spyder as well and same results. Why can't I recursively call a method within a method in this example?

Also tried this code, and it works, but only when I remove the keywords 'self' and 'object' and removed the class definition, why is that?

Before (Error: TypeError: climbStairs() missing 1 required positional argument: 'n')

```
def climbStairs(self, n):
    if n in {0,1}:
        return 1
    else:
        return climbStairs(n-2) + climbStairs(n-1)
    
print(climbStairs(object, 8))
```

After (WORKS! without class def, 'self' and 'object' keywords):

```
def climbStairs(n):
    if n in {0,1}:
        return 1
    else:
        return climbStairs(n-2) + climbStairs(n-1)
    
print(climbStairs(8))
```

What does the class def, keyword 'self' and 'object' add to the code? Why do I need them?

Comment: It should be `self.climbStairs`. But why are you using a class? This seems like it should be an ordinary function.

Comment: You need to read a tutorial on Python OOP to understand the basics like `self`.

Comment: @Barmar Because LeetCode requires that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You working code should like following

**Code:**

```
class Solution(object):
    
    def climbStairs(self, n):
        if n in {0,1}:
            return 1
        else:
            return self.climbStairs(n-2) + self.climbStairs(n-1)

print(Solution().climbStairs(8))
```

**Output:**

```
34
```

> The issue is with the recursive function call. You have to add `self` to call a function of a class.

Comment: Thanks! why is it print(Solution().climbStairs(8)) and not just print(climbStairs(8)). What is the diff there?

Comment: If I want to call the `climbStairs` function I have to call it through class object. Without class object system can't identify a class function. :)

Comment: @Winston_01 the difference is that one creates an instance of the `Solution` class and calls its `climbStairs` method, while the other would try to call a function `climbStairs` which doesn't exist.

Comment: @Sabil ah that makes sense, because the function exists within the class, and the only way to make the function run is to first create an object for it to run off of. Simply calling a method doesn't make sense without an object. Leetcode kind of makes it seem like you can run things without objects first and simply write a method and then run it on the fly.

Comment: Yeah. If you debug then you can notice that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to call your method with `self`:

```
return self.climbStairs(n-2) + self.climbStairs(n-1)
```